# Which Serializer or Adapter is best to work in ember js?

Tags: ember.js

**Can somebody explain with example about how to work with JSONSerializer ,RESTSerializer and JSONAPISerializer ?**
I'm having a hard time working with different types of Serializer and adaptor  but I know the basics of Serializer(To convert the payload from/to backend to/from store as it's convenience) and Adapter(To specify the backend url and namespace and headers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that **You have to choose the Serializer or Adaptor from JSONAPISerializer , JSONSerializer,RESTSerializer which suits  best for your Backend API or REST API's response JSON form**

Meanwhile if you still want to use any particular Serializer let's say JSONAPISerializer You have to explicitly transform your backend JSON API's Response (payload) to JSONAPISerializer's expected JSON form
by overriding the appropriate methods in JSONAPISerializer class  for example normalizeResponse(),normalizeArrayResponse()..etc

link to learn about those methods

https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.3/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer/methods

To learn about the formats expected by every serializers see the below link

https://thejsguy.com/2015/12/05/which-ember-data-serializer-should-i-use.html